# Multiple data types array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, although I couldn't find an exact answer for this anywhere:
**Is there a way to create an array in *postgreSQL* which contains multiple data types?**

I have an column of type `text[]` (array of type text); although I'd like to insert into this array three `text` entries and then a fourth entry, from type `integer`.

Is there a way to do so? If so, how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to declare an array with multiple types; however, I think you can accomplish what you are trying to do with a [composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/rowtypes.html), e.g.,

```
create type my_item as (
    field_1        text,
    field_2        text,
    field_3        text,
    field_4        number
);
```

You could then use this as the column type for your table or even declare a column of arrays of `my_item[]` if that fits your need.

Comment: Should I write this code in python file? or inside postgres? (if yes where? )

Comment: You CAN use JSON(B) to accomplish this task. Ex: `SELECT '[1, "text", true]'::JSONB;` but there are limitations with that, namely that JSON only supports a limited number of data types which don't match 1:1 with postgres' native data types. But it is a quick basic solution that isn't necessarily hacky.