# Using Django ArrayField to Store Dates and Value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm currently having a hard time wrapping my head around Django's Array Field. What i'm hoping to do is have an array that looks something like this:

```
Price(close=[
    [1/1/2018, 3.00],
    [1/2/2018, 1.00],
])
```

It's basically an array that stores a date followed by a corresponding value tied to that date. However, thus far my model looks like this:

```
class Price(models.Model):
    close = ArrayField(
            models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4),
            size=365,           
        )
```

I am not certain how to create an array with two different types of fields, one DateTime, the other decimal. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix types stored in the `ArrayField`. [1] I recommend you to change model schema (aka Database normalization [2]).

This is my suggestion:

```py
from django.db import models


class Price(models.Model):
    pass


class PriceItem(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    ammount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/8168017/752142

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Gotcha, I'm confused though as to why `PriceItem.price` is a foreign key to the `Price` model.

Comment: You want to store a sequence (array) of pair values (date and decimal). You cannot do this with `ArrayField`: A) values are of different types; B) it is not normalized (1NF). My suggestion is: store each pair of values (items of the array) as rows in the database (an instance of `PriceItem`). Then you need to associate `n` rows (items of the array) together --> that's why I suggested `ForeignKey` to `Price` model. Maybe if you describe your use case, I could think of something better.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how important it is to the model.

postgresql provides [composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/rowtypes.html)

The generous contributor of psycopg2 (django's posgresql driver) is supporting [it](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#composite-types-casting),

define this type in postgresql:

```
   CREATE TYPE date_price AS (
       start date,
       float8 price
   );
```

and using [the methods described here](http://schinckel.net/2014/09/24/using-postgres-composite-types-in-django/) to implement CompositeField

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
   from django.db import connection
   from psycopg2.extras import register_composite

   # register the composite 

   register_composite('date_price', connection.cursor().cursor)


   # CompositeField implementation here . . . . . .



   class DatePriceField(CompositeField):
       '''
       DatePriceField specifics
       '''
       pass

   class Price(models.Model):
       close = ArrayField(base_field=DatePriceField(), size=365,)
```

I am going to follow this route and update soon.

Comment: Where should I write the first code block? (the one that create date_price)